# Word2Vec Vocabulary not definded error

Tags: python, word2vec

I am new to python and word2vec and keep getting a "you must first build vocabulary before training the model" error. What is wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
file_object=open("SupremeCourt.txt","w")
from gensim.models import word2vec

data = word2vec.Text8Corpus('SupremeCourt.txt')
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(data, size=200)

out=model.most_similar()

print(out[1])
print(out[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see some wrong things in your code like the file is opened in write mode and the model which you have loaded doesn't contain the word which you want to find the most similar words. 
I would like to suggest to use the predefined models like [google_news_vectors](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit) to load in the gensim or to build your own word2vec [model](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/10/09/generating-a-word2vec-model-from-a-block-of-text-using-gensim-python/) so that you won't get the error.
the usage of most_similar in gensim is `out = model.most_similar("word-name")`

```
file_object=open("SupremeCourt.txt","r")
from gensim.models import word2vec

data = word2vec.Text8Corpus('SupremeCourt.txt')
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(data, size=200)#use google news vectors here 

out=model.most_similar("word")
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're opening that file in write mode with this line:

```
file_object = open("SupremeCourt.txt", "w")
```

By doing this, you're erasing the contents of your file, so that when you try to pass the file the model for training, there is no data to read. That's why that error is thrown.

Remove that line (and also restore your file contents), and it'll work.

Comment: Make sure you have redownloaded the file before, as the changes were written to disk.